# How do I foreground a job in a script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, background-process

I want to launch a test, then wait a little and then start a program, using a shell script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
sleep 3 &  # test
sleep 1    # wait some
sleep 4 &  # run program under test
fg 1       # <-- I want to put test back in "foreground", but yields "line 5: fg: no job control"
```

I presume I misunderstood what "foreground" means, but is there some other way to do what I want? (I tried prefixing with `jobs -x` and `nohup`, but I suspect my misunderstanding runs deeper.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to just enable job control in the shell with `set -m`

```
#!/bin/bash
set -m
sleep 3 &  # test
sleep 1    # wait some
sleep 4 &  # run program under test
jobs
fg %1
```

quoting from bash manual:

> -m
>
> Monitor mode. Job control is enabled. This option is on by default for
> interactive shells on systems that support it (see JOB CONTROL above).
> Background processes run in a separate process group and a line
> containing their exit status is printed upon their completion.

Comment: You do not know if %1 is sleep 3 or sleep 4.if sleep 3 has already finished when sleep 4 started then sleep 4 is job %1

Comment: Backgrounded jobs are numbered sequentially even if previous ones have finished, so each job increments the counter, finished or not.

Better is not to use job numbers if possible - if job 1 was 'testscript' and job 3 was 'myprog' then you can use the job identifier %te or %myp
So long as it is not ambiguous, this is simpler to track

Answer (score 23):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

sleep 3 & sleep_pid=$!
sleep 1
sleep 4 &
wait "$sleep_pid"
```

Putting that `sleep 3` in the foreground would be equivalent to waiting for it to finish.  I'm assuming this is what you want to do (or at least that this is the *effect* that you're looking for), which is what the script above does.  It does this by saving the PID of the job in the variable `sleep_pid` and then using that value in a call to `wait`.

Comment: Is this really equivalent, including in terms of `SIGTSTP` and `SIGINT` from terminal input?  (Genuine question; I'd like to know)

Comment: @TobySpeight It is not equivalent in terms of signals, AFAIK. I tried to be explicit about what the my code does, which is to wait for the `sleep 3` call to finish.  I'm assuming this is what the user wanted. The effect of putting a call to `sleep` in the foreground is to wait for it to finish. If the user wanted to put it in the foreground for any _particular_ reason, they failed to mention it.

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda; I feel better informed now.